# Git Error while starting wp-env on windows 10

Tags: wordpress, npm, wordpress-gutenberg

I am not able to start wp-env and I also don't understand the error I get. I've installed wp-env, docker and all the other things I need.

I am working on Windows 10 and my account is an administrator.
"D:\OneDrive\webseiten\wpdev\wp-content\plugins\starter" is a ready to run wp-plugin.

When I try to start wp-env, I get following error:

```
D:\OneDrive\webseiten\wpdev\wp-content\plugins\starter>wp-env start --update
× Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
GitError: Error: spawn git ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at Object.action (C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:1228:25)
    at PluginStore.exec (C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:1263:29)
    at C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:1627:43
    at new Promise ()
    at GitExecutorChain.handleTaskData (C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:1625:16)
    at GitExecutorChain. (C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:1609:44)
    at Generator.next ()
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@wordpress\env\node_modules\simple-git\dist\cjs\index.js:55:24) {
  task: {
    commands: [
      'clone',
      '--depth=1',
      '--no-single-branch',
      'https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git',
      'D:\\OneDrive\\webseiten\\wp-env\\7d7d92c3d29a7ac077cdad60da98c0fd\\WordPress'
    ],
    format: 'utf-8',
    parser: [Function: parser]
  }
}
```

The overridden WP_ENV_HOME is not the problem, I got the same error with the default WP_ENV_HOME.

Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
For me it was solved by installing git and making sure that the terminal from where I am running `wp-env` knows where to find the `git` command:

```
PS C:\Users\me> git
git : The term 'gitr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or [...]
```

After installing git and system restart:

```
PS C:\Users\me> git
usage: git [-v | --version] [-h | --help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [--config-env=<name>=<envvar>] <command> [<args>]

These are common Git commands used in various situations: [...]
```